# Convert BBcode to HTML using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

Could I please get some help with coverting some PHP code to jQuery/JavaScript? What I want is a simple BBCode to HTML converter.

Here is the PHP code. I want to achieve the same thing using jQuery/JavaScript.

```
$str = htmlentities($str);

// The array of regex patterns to look for
$format_search =  array(
    '#\[b\](.*?)\[/b\]#is',
    '#\[i\](.*?)\[/i\]#is',
    '#\[u\](.*?)\[/u\]#is',
);

// The matching array of strings to replace matches with
$format_replace = array(
    '<strong>$1</strong>',
    '<em>$1</em>',
    '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</span>',
);

// Perform the actual conversion
$str = preg_replace($format_search, $format_replace, $str);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks ALMOST like you just need to change `#` to `/` and `is` to `ig` but I also had to change `/b` to `\/b`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/m8zLX/)

```
$str = 'this is a [b]bolded[/b] and [i]italic[/i] string';

// The array of regex patterns to look for
$format_search =  [
    /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig,
    /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/ig,
    /\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/ig
]; // note: NO comma after the last entry

// The matching array of strings to replace matches with
$format_replace = [
    '<strong>$1</strong>',
    '<em>$1</em>',
    '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</span>'
];

// Perform the actual conversion
for (var i =0;i<$format_search.length;i++) {
  $str = $str.replace($format_search[i], $format_replace[i]);
}
alert($str)
```

---

[**Other Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/UDS6f/)

```
function boldFunc(str, p1, offset, s) {
  return '<strong>'+encodeURIComponent(p1)+'</strong>'
}

function italicFunc(str, p1, offset, s) {
  return '<em>'+encodeURIComponent(p1)+'</em>'
}

function underlinedFunc(str, p1, offset, s) {
  return '<span class="un">'+encodeURIComponent(p1)+'</span>'
}


$str = 'this is a [b]bölded[/b], [i]itälic[/i] and [u]ünderlined[/u] [i]strïng[/i]';

// The array of regex patterns to look for
$format_search =  [
    /\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig,
    /\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/ig,
    /\[u\](.*?)\[\/u\]/ig
]; // NOTE: No comma after the last entry

// The matching array of strings to replace matches with
$format_replace = [
    boldFunc,
    italicFunc,
    underlinedFunc
];

// Perform the actual conversion
for (var i =0;i<$format_search.length;i++) {
  $str = $str.replace($format_search[i], $format_replace[i]);
}
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=$str;
```

Comment: I don´t know the name of the functions to use in javascript/jQuery. I supposed it´s not preg_replace as in PHP.

Comment: Is there any way to run a function on $1? I need to run encodeURIComponent() on $1. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this. I have forked this to include phpbb with uid bbcodes that uses jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/2Zfvk/