# Replace bbcode tags with HTML equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bbcode

I want to make a script that previews your entered bbcode text as it will appear when posted, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Basically if a user enters in a `textarea` the following:

```
[b]This[/b] is some [url=http://google.com]sample[/url] text.
```

I want to show the user a preview of the above; like this:

> **This** is some [sample](http://google.com) text.

The preview will just be a separate `<p>` somewhere on the page. I was first considering just replacing all brackets `[ ]` with `< >` but this would only work for certain tags. The `url`-tag for example is quite different from the HTML equivalent.

So I'm stuck. Any ideas if this is possible with javascript or jQuery?

EDIT: I should note that the tags I'm interested in are: b, i, u, url, color, and size.

Comment: Is this of any use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210680/convert-bbcode-to-html-using-javascript-jquery ? If not, where/how does it fail to do as you require?

Comment: This only seems to do the [b], [i] and [u] tags. As I said in my question, the real problem are with the other tags, such as [font], [url] and [color].

Comment: This might be a starting point for you http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/46751/bbcode-to-html-converter-using-functional-programming.