# tinymce convert bbcode to html code

Tags: extjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, extjs6, bbcode

I want that my tinymce convert the bbcode to html code. I am adding tinymce in Extjs 6. When I want to make the Bold, it writes me in the html code [b] and it is the same thing for: italic, underlined, size.
I follow this link but it's  not working too: [Convert BBcode to HTML using JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210680/convert-bbcode-to-html-using-javascript-jquery)
How can change that please, because it is showing on my website like this: 
[b]Test[/b] instead of **Test**
This my code:

```
tinyMCEConfig: {
                                content_style: "iframe { width:100%}",

                                plugins : [
                                  'advlist anchor autolink autoresize autosave bbcode charmap link code image imagetools codesample contextmenu colorpicker code lists charmap print  hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
                                  'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking example fullscreen importcss media ',
                                  'save paste preview table template textcolor textpattern  visualblocks visualchars wordcount searchreplace spellchecker tabfocus contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor  textpattern insertdatetime layer lists'
                                ], 
                                menubar: 'insert edit view',

                                image_advtab: true ,

                                external_filemanager_path:"/ext/ux/newtinymce/js/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/",
                                filemanager_title:"Responsive Filemanager" ,
                                external_plugins: { "filemanager" : "/ext/ux/newtinymce/js/responsive_filemanager/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
                                toolbar1: 'responsivefilemanager bold italic underline strikethrough alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify numlist bullist anchor ',
                                toolbar2: 'code codesample preview hr  textcolor fullpage textpattern  layer lists emoticons media image imagetools fontsizeselect fontselect',
                                toolbar3: 'ltr rtl visualblocks  searchreplace insertdatetime nonbreaking fullscreen indent pagebreak template ',
                                toolbar4: 'save cancel pastetext paste  print table  importcss  textcolor  backcolor  textpattern wordcount   lists  contextmenu restoredraft bbcode  charmap link instagram',
                                bbcode_dialect: "punbb",
                                autoresize_max_height: 50,
                                fontsize_formats : "8pt 8.25pt 8.5pt 8.75pt 9pt 9.25pt 9.5pt 10pt 11pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
                                font_formats: 'Schriftart=Schriftart;Microsoft Sans Serif=Microsoft Sans Serif;Sans-serif = sans-serif;Andale Mono=andale mono,times;Arial=arial, helvetica, sans-serif;Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Book Antiqua=book antiqua; Palatino = palatino;'+
                                'Comic Sans MS=comic sans ms,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Impact=impact,chicago;'+
                                'Symbol=symbol;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif; Serif = serif;Terminal=terminal,monaco;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;'+
                                'Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva;Webdings=webdings;Wingdings=wingdings,zapf dingbats',
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you enable in 
[PunBB.INFO](https://punbb.info) → Administration → Settings → Features
option

**Message options**     Allow BBCode in posts (recommended).

Comment: Thank for your post but I just remove the bbcode plugin and I got the the html code of my content.