# Convert Bbcode to plain text

Tags: angularjs, bbcode

I am using angular application. I want to convert the bbcode into plain text. Is there any any plugin or library or any method for it. I am accepting following data.

```
$scope.Currentdata= "[justify][size=2]New testing.Hello World.[/size][/justify]";
```

and i want to remove the bbcode and show plain text on my div.

```
<div id="showdata" name="showdata"></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210680/convert-bbcode-to-html-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following plugin to parse :

> https://github.com/DasRed/js-bbcode-parser

Use the following command:

> bower install bbcode-parser --save

```
// use to create a clean parser
var parser = new BBCode({}, {})

// use default parser
var parser = BBCode.default

// configure the default parser with
BBCode.setCodes({});

console.log(BBCode.default.parse('This is a text[br]with HTML Break.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a string to blank text (not html), you can use [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) [Patterns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to filter out the tags.

Since all tags are basically `[(/)x=y]` you can remove anything between the square brackets and the brackets themselves.