# How can I replace characters with html tag? (enriching text)

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, replace, lodash

Text = "I have this text [b] and want this part to be bold [/b]."

How can i replace the [b] and [/b] with **strong** html tag

so that the output is => I have this text **and want this part to be bold**.

I tried using lodash replace like this but eslint is complaining for the closing tag:

```
let startTag = _.replace(text, '[b]', <strong>);
let endTag= _.replace(startTag, '[/b]', </strong>);
```

Comment: What you had tried?

Comment: Show us some code you have tried till now.

Comment: After 'and' you want bold?

Comment: Can you add the entire string you wish to change?

Comment: Wrap `<strong>` with quote `'<strong>'` (same for the closing tag)

Comment: Since OP mentioned in comment of my answer that he was using react and jsx, it change the question a lot. I created a whole other Q&A about inspired by this one. Check this one if you are looking to output some bbcode in react: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629664/how-can-i-convert-bbcode-characters-to-jsx-enriching-text/59629665#59629665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution in java-script looks like this:

```
var str = 'I have this text [b] and want this part to be bold [/b].';
str = str.replace(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig, '<strong>$1</strong>');
console.log(str);
```

Comment: not working for me...eslint is complaining regarding the redundant character escape.

Comment: ignoring the redundant character escape, it will print the text without interpreting the <strong> tag

Comment: function main(str) {
  str = str.replace(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/ig, '<strong>$1</strong>');
  return str;
}
var str = 'I have this text [b] and want this part to be bold [/b].';
main(str);

I checked with JShint.com and it shows no error or warning :- 
There is only one function in this file.
It takes one argument.
This function contains 2 statements.
Cyclomatic complexity number for this function is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to wrap `<strong>` with quote `'<strong>'` (same for the closing tag).

```js
let text = 'foo [b]bar[/b]';
let startTag = _.replace(text, '[b]', '<strong>');
let endTag = _.replace(startTag, '[/b]', '</strong>');
document.write(endTag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This markup look like [BBCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode). You may want to use an existing bbcode parser instead of building one. (check your favorite browser engine to find solution like [Extendible-BBCode-Parser](https://github.com/patorjk/Extendible-BBCode-Parser), [js-bbcode-parser](https://github.com/DasRed/js-bbcode-parser), [node-bbcode](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-bbcode), or even on Stack Overflow [Convert BBcode to HTML using JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210680/convert-bbcode-to-html-using-javascript-jquery)).

Comment: thanks but this will print the text with the tags: I have this text <strong> and want this part to be bold </strong>. Maybe is it because I'm working with jsx

Comment: @Eskoby Add the tag jsx to your question. You never mentioned it until now. By the way, do you plan to support bbcode or only the `[b]` tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use loadash then do like below.

```js
var text = "I have this text [b] and want this part to be bold [/b]."
var openedTag = text.replace("[b]", "<strong>");
var closedTag = openedTag.replace("[/b]", "</strong>");
document.write(closedTag)
```

Comment: same issue like i commented above...the <strong> tag is not being interpreted