# How can I convert bbcode characters to jsx? (enriching text)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, bbcode

Text = "I have this text [b] and want this part to be bold [/b]."

How can I replace the `[b]` and `[/b]` with **strong** html tag

so that the output is => I have this text **and want this part to be bold**.

I tried using lodash replace like this but eslint is complaining for the closing tag:

```
let startTag = _.replace(text, '[b]', <strong>);
let endTag= _.replace(startTag, '[/b]', </strong>);
```

[mcve](https://repl.it/repls/RedundantAbsoluteSdk)

Comment: you example is not valid; that's probably why eslint is complaining.

Comment: It could be fix with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx). But since you are looking to parse BBCode, use a bbcode parser.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a basic replace, you should rely on an existing library to achieve this. If you build an homemade solution, you will end with a poor version of another library. Here I will use the library at the top of "react bbcode" on my favorite search engine. Ok lets run [`bbcode-to-react`](https://npm.taobao.org/package/bbcode-to-react). They even have an example. Lets copy paste it to your mcve.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import parser from 'bbcode-to-react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{parser.toReact('foo [b]bar[/b]')}</p>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

ouput:

foo **bar**

Alright. You can try it on repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/SeagreenDarkcyanNumerator

Comment: By the way if there is a better solution I would love to read it. This one fix the problem as expected, but it could be better. A better solution could take the form of a buildin mode of react use to handle BBCode markup  (a premade component for example).